# Utilize local library in Webpack 3

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a folder structure similar to the following:

```
+Module
+-Source
+--A bunch of stuff
+-package.json
+Website
+-package.json
```

The website is a development site built in Angular for helping build the library. Previously it was setup with SystemJS and I had a gulp task copy the files from `Module/Source` into the site's `node_modules/Module`. It worked fine; and an actual client site using SystemJS was able to load the package via standard `npm install`.

Now I'm trying to convert the dev site to webpack. I *could* leave the gulp task in but that would be the last task I have. Moreover it is my understanding that webpack should be able to handle this.

Unfortunately, I have tried the following with no success:

1. `npm link` to "Module"

   - Builds, but I get a runtime error saying it can't find Angular's Router
2. Add "../Module/Source" to my webpack config's `resolve` item

   ```
   resolve: {
      modules: [
        '../Module/Source',
        'node_modules'
      ],
      extensions: ['.ts', '.scss', '.html']
   }
   ```

   - This results in the webpack build completely ignoring my library. It completes very quickly and throws a bunch of errors that it can't resolve symbols from the library
   - I've tried this with and without the extensions array and adding a trailing slash to "Source" all with the same result
   - Originally I got this sort of working (not sure how) but it complained about multiple instances of node_modules (I didn't have the "Source" folder yet). I have been unable to get anything going with the "Source" folder.
3. Use "CopyWebpackPlugin" to do the same thing my gulpfile did originally. This would probably work, but I can't figure out the right options for the plugin.

I would like to know what the correct approach is to configure webpack for this, and what syntax I need to make it work.